# How to reset/change a variables value if while loop condition false in php

Tags: php

I have situation where i want to set some value to a php variable in a while loop. Please have a look at my code for better understanding.

```
$radioChecked = '';
$j=1;

while($j <= $someNumber){
$radioChecked = 'checked';
$j++; 
}
```

Now i want after finishing while loop my `$radioChecked` variable should have an empty string.

Actually i am trying to do this: 
i have some Radio buttons and i want to check some of them. how many checkboxes will be checked it will be depending on `$someNumber` variable.

Then i have checkboxes down:

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total_radios; $i++){
    <input type="radio" <?php echo $radioChecked; ?> />
    }
```

Now here is the problem:

if i have 4 `$total_radios` then i am getting 4 radios displayed on the page which is good as i expecting that. If `$someNumber` is 2 then i want first 2 radio buttons to be checked. If `$someNumber` is 3 then i want first 3 radio buttons to be checked and so on.

But in my case it is checking all the Radio Buttons. I need some logic to reset `$radioChecked` variable to empty string if condition while loop condition false.

How can i do this?
Thanks.

Comment: "_Now i want after finishing while loop my $checkbox variable should have an empty string._" There is no `$checkbox` variable.

Comment: Sorry. i meant $radioChecked) i have updated the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the test against `$someNumber` around the `echo` statement.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $total_radios; $i++){ ?>
    <input type="radio" <?php if ($i < $someNumber) echo $radioChecked; ?> />
<?php 
}
```

You were also missing the `?>` and `<?php` around the HTML body of the `for` loop.

Comment: I am using Laravel blade i just recreated this scenario to understand better.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just do it in the loop?

```
foreach ($total_radios as $i => $total){
    <input type="radio" <?php if ($i < $someNumber) echo 'checked'; ?> />
}
```

Mish-mash between php and html but the provided example is the same.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The problem is `$total_radios`  is not an array . it is an integer.

Comment: `foreach (range(0, $total_radios - 1) ... ` then :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks like this is also a good solution. i Will give a try sure. Thank you for the answer. )

Answer (score 0):

I think this would also work as a solution:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $total_radios; $i++){
    <input type="radio" <?php echo $radioChecked; ?> />
    $j--;
    if ($j == 0) {
        $radioChecked = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing `?>` before the `<input`